# How do use setInterval() the correct way?

Tags: javascript

I'm fairly new to javascript and I'm trying to make the box #aDiv move some pixels every second when I click the "setInterval" button, and also make it stop when I press "setTimeout" button. I don't know what to write in the function called "move" without getting any errors. If someone could please guide me through or help me I'd deeply appreciate it.

**Here's my code**

````
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <style>
   #aDiv{
       background-color: yellow;
       width: 150px;
       height: 150px;
       position: absolute;
       left: 10px;
       top: 200px;
       border-radius: 20px;
       box-shadow: 2.5px 2.5px 5px 2.5px black;
   }
   </style>
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" onclick="setInterval()">Set interval</button><br>
    <button type="button" onclick="">Set timeout</button><br>
    <button type="button" onclick="myTimeoutFunction"> Clear timeout</button><br>
    <button type="button" onclick=myStopFunction""> Clear interval</button><br>

    <div id="aDiv"></div>
    <script>
var event = document.getElementById("aDiv");
var second = 1;
var myVar;

function setInterval(){
  myVar = setInterval(move,1000);
}

function move(){
    var eLeftPos = event.offsetLeft;
    event.style.left = (eLeftPos + second) + 'px';
}


function moveX(){
    document.getElementsByClassName("box").left = 100;
}
function myTimeoutFunction() {
  clearTimeout(myVar);
}

function myStopFunction() {
  clearInterval(myVar);
}

    </script>
</body>
</html> ```
````

Comment: You shouldn't name your function `setInterval`.

Comment: Can you show us the error that you are getting in the console?. Thank you

Comment: Your `setInterval` function is calling *itself*, repeatedly and for ever, **not** the builtin one.

Answer (score 0):

As it has been said, you shouldn't name your function `setInterval`. You're overriding your browser's `setInterval` function and it is calling itself indefinitely. Also, your `event` variable contains a DOM element, which does not make sense. Why not name it something like `elem`?

A good habit would also be not to add event listeners directly in your HTML (`onclick="..."`).

I'm not totally sure I understood your question, is this what you are trying to do? (click the blue button below the code to try it)

```js
var startBtn = document.getElementById("start-btn"),
    pauseBtn = document.getElementById("pause-btn"),
    resetBtn = document.getElementById("reset-btn"),
    elem = document.getElementById("aDiv"),
    second = 1,
    myInterval;
    
startBtn.addEventListener('click', startAnimation);
pauseBtn.addEventListener('click', pauseAnimation);
resetBtn.addEventListener('click', resetAnimation);

function startAnimation(){
  // We don't want it to run multiples times in parallel
  pauseAnimation();
  myInterval = setInterval(move, 50);
}

function pauseAnimation(){
  clearInterval(myInterval);
}

function resetAnimation(){
  pauseAnimation();
  elem.style.left = '10px';
}

function move(){
  var eLeftPos = elem.offsetLeft;
  elem.style.left = (eLeftPos + second ) + 'px';
}
```

```css
#aDiv{
   background-color: yellow;
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   position: absolute;
   left: 10px;
   top: 50px;
   border-radius: 20px;
   box-shadow: 2.5px 2.5px 5px 2.5px black;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="start-btn">Start</button>
<button type="button" id="pause-btn">Pause</button>
<button type="button" id="reset-btn">Reset</button>

<div id="aDiv"></div>
```